# How do I make Vim respect Markdown headers when formating text?

Tags: formatting, wrapping, filetype-markdown

I want to use the combination `gggqG` to go to the top of the file and format the whole file from there, so that it fits into my 80 col textwidth border.

But when I do, vim ignores my markdown headers. So I want basically to ignore all markdown headers for formatting. How can I do that?

**before**

```
#this is a h1
this is the text of the file i want 
to reformat
```

**after**

```
#this is a h1 this
is the text of the file
i want to reformat
```

The word `this` was moved to the header.

Comment: what is your formatoptions setting?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt `formatoptions=t,a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you don't have wrapping for comments enabled, the workaround in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686502/2072269) can be used:

```
set comments+=n:#
set fo+=q
```

This adds `#` as a comment marker (allowing `n`esting, so that `##`, `###`, etc. also count).

I'd suggest leaving a space after `#` and using `nb:#` - some Markdown parsers require a space after `#`. The [CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/#atx-headers) also supports this.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to change the way you write your Markdown slightly, you could fix this simply by introducing an extra blank line between your headings and the following text:

```
# this is a h1

this is the text of the file i want
to reformat
```

This is how I personally format my atx-style Markdown headers, anyway: I think it looks better and is easier to read.

Comment: Seconded, this is how I write too. Many things in Markdown benefit from blank lines around them.

Comment: After posting my question i've noticed this too, but @muru 's stackoverflow link more helpful in my "general problem", so thanks I'll upvoted your post.