# How can I make vim's flowing aware of email replies?

Tags: formatting, wrapping

## Problem summary

I use `vim` to edit emails that I send with `mutt`. I also use `format=flowed`, which "reflows" text. That is, lines are limited to a fixed number of characters, and a "soft wrap" is applied, as indicated by the presence of a trailing space.

In `vim`, I have the following set:

```
setl tw=72
setl fo=aw
```

This sets the line length to 72 charaters, and sets up autoformatting with the trailing space. This works well in general. However, if I attempt to quote something with `>`, this character is not treated as a special character, and will be considered "inline" to the text.

## Example

Copy the following text and paste it into `vim`.

```
Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing nullam nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve. [1]
```

`vim` correctly breaks it into two lines, the first with a trailing space.

```
Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing nullam 
nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve. [1]
```

I add `>` by selecting the lines and using `:'<,'>s/^/> /`, which results in the following.

```
> Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing nullam 
> nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve. [1]
```

However, I now want to remove the `[1]` from the end, so I navigate to the end and delete. `vim` now reflows to the following, with the `>` "inline".

```
> Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing 
nullam > nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve.
```

What's even worse is that I can delete the `>` manually and insert a new `>` before `nullam`, but this will immediately be reflowed to the previous line as follows.

```
> Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing > 
nullam nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve.
```

## Question

Is there a way to make `vim`'s flowing aware of `>`? FWIW I've also tried [this](https://gist.github.com/wcaleb/633a63e9c29887493d3f) `mail.vim` customised for format=flowed, but it suffers from the same problems.

Comment: For the note, you can do it manually using `gqap` in normal mode. I actually prefer to do it manually than having to fight it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [one of my previous answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6034/205), you can get this to work if:

1. You have `nb:>` in your `comments` setting.
2. And you have `q` in your `formatoptions` setting.

So:

```
setlocal comments+=nb:>
setlocal fo+=q
```

After doing these, I get the expected wrapping:

```
> Tempus. Vivamus. Dis natoque vitae erat. Consectetuer adipiscing 
> nullam nec gravida non, at posuere enim, consectetuer ve.
```

Comment: Thanks! That works well. However, wouldn't `setlocal` make more sense? Also, could you please explain `set fo+=q`? I looked in the help and it said `q` was `Allow formatting of comments with "gq"…`, which seemed to suggest it wouldn't alter the *automatic* formatting.

Comment: @Sparhawk `setlocal` would be better yes, these were commands I manually entered, so I just went with `set`. I don't know why `q` affects this, but it does, and has done so for some time now, as the trail of links shows. :/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. I'll accept this answer because it's minimal and hence easier to follow the help.

Comment: Just noting that the `b` in `nb:>` is unnecessary to get the desired effect, and, off the top of my head, might not be desired for `format=flowed` (because `> > text` means something different from `>> text` in f=f.)

Answer (score 2):

`setlocal formatoptions=jawtcqln` worked for me. I'd put it in `~/.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim`.

Comment: That's half of the `formatoptions` strings right there. Can you explain which particular combination of these solves this problem?

Comment: Thank you, that works. FWIW the `q` option is key here. i.e. in combination, the minimum that works for me is `setl fo=awq`.